# How does angular binding happen?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch, angularjs-bindings

Below is my understanding of how binding happens in angularJS. Would be great if experts can provide feedback/comment..

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlA">
  {{myvar}}
  {{anothervar}}
</div>

$scope.watch( function (scope) {
    return scope.anothervar;
  } ,  function (oldValue, newValue) {
    // code to manupilate HTML with new value!!
  });

$scope.watch( function (scope) {
    return scope.myVar;
  } ,  function (oldValue, newValue) {
    // code to manipulate HTML with new value!!
  });
```

As soon as angularJS encounters {{myVar}} (and {{anothervar}}) a watcher (for each variable) is created internally. This watcher is created for $scope of controller 'ctrlA'.

Whenever functions are called within $timeout, ng-click etc they are embedded within $scope.apply(). After your function is executed (which might change some scope variables), $apply will call digest on the rootScope. This will sync variables throughout the app with the UI!

When $scope.digest is called it iterates through all the watchers for that scope. It then gets the current value of the variable and checks to see if it changed. If it changed it calls the watcher handler (which changes the html to reflect the new value!).

I have a **question** here. Does angularJS store have some kind of key-map (or some data structure) for every scope, which contains the reference to watcher and the current value for that watcher?? Something like:

```
watch ref (for myvar) -> current value (of myvar)
watch ref (for anothervar) -> current value (of anothervar)
```

Comment: Part of your answer is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of how Angular sets up a watcher for each binding is *pretty much* right on the money. I'll go ahead and jump straight to the *question*, as opposed to debunking/discussing your point of view of what the inner workings of Angular bindings look like.

> I have a question here. Does angularJS store have some kind of key-map (or some data structure) for every scope, which contains the reference to watcher and the current value for that watcher??

`$scope` has an internal array of currently active watchers (`.$$watchers`) attached to said scope, where an entry would look as such:

[image]

*The explanation below is **wrong**. See my edit for correction(s)*

- `eq` is a boolean dictating whether the expression in `fn` holds
  true/false.
- `exp` is the raw string value that you exposed in your view between the 'squiggles' `{{raw_expr_value}}`.
- I *believe* that `fn` is a reference to the internal [$interpolate.$$watchDelegate](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js#L294) (or as you put it, *"a reference to the watcher"*). If this were a manual `$scope.$watch('val', _func_)`, `fn` would be a reference to `_func_`.
- `get` *I'm not so sure about.* If anyone could fill in on what this is, that'd be super.
- And `last` is the latest value the expression evaluated to.

With all of that said, ordinarily you shouldn't be touching the internal `$$` variables, but if you must - go right ahead. *Tread lightly :)*

---

### Edit

I was in the wrong. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L372) of `$watch`, the properties are as follows:

- `fn` - the callback function for your watcher.
- `last` - [src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1328) a *unique* value applied at the very beginning of the setup of `$watch`. Probably so as to trigger the expression to evaluate initially.
- `get` - The expression wrapped with `$parse()`.
- `exp` - [prettyPrintExpression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L378) which is something I have **never** heard about before. Falls back to the watched expression in your view / `$watch` handler.
- `eq` - This is where I was **oh so very wrong**. The boolean dictates whether we're doing a deep watch (object equality) or a regular shallow watch.

Comment: I played with Angular prettyPrintExpression : it seems (as of 1.5.0) that it sometimes contains the raw watched expression from a DOM binding. Ex. `ng-class="{active: $state.includes('profile')}` will cause a watch with `prettyPrintExpression`=`{active: $state.includes('profile')}` but a complex watching function in `get` / `listener`. This is definitely useful for logging ! (as hinted by the "pretty print")